# How do I configure github autodeploy on heroku using just the heroku REST Platform API

Tags: rest, heroku, github

I've searched the platform API docs on heroku and it doesn't appear to be possible.  Is there some currently undocumented way to set the github link and enable autodeploy, just using the REST API? I know how to do it through the website, so this is specifically about doing it via REST commands ( specifically I'm using the heroku-client nodejs wrapper but I don't think that's relevant )
Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no public API for the GitHub integration so far.
You have to do it through the website.